# Merging text files horizontally

Tags: python, numpy, text, merge

So I have 20 txt files. 10 are

```
A_1,A_2......A_10
```

and the other 10 are

```
B_1,B_2.....B_3......B_10
```

So, basically, i am trying to merge `A_1` and `B_1`, `A_2` and `B_2`........, `A_10` and `B_10` horizontally ( that means if had 4 columns each in `A` and `B`, I want the output to have 8). I also want to save these 10 merged files. I am really new in Python, so not sure how to go about.

```
import numpy as np
filelist=[]
filelist1=[]
for i in range(1,11):
    filelist.append("/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/A_%s.txt" %i)
for j in range(1,11):
    filelist1.append("/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/B_%s.txt" %j)
```

Comment: append adds to the end. you want to read in a line 1 from a_1 and b_1. then combine those lines, `newline = aLine + bLine` then write new line to a new file. Then just keep reading in lines, combining, and writing to a new a file. You should at least try to read in the files and write to a new one. The code you posted barely counts as an attempt.

Comment: Alternative way: You could read them to dataframes with pandas and use df concat: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html

Comment: Can you show the first several lines of any of the files? If you want to use numpy, then they have to be read into arrays, and the format is important.

Comment: I tried some codes, but they were not working, so I only posted portion of the code that worked where I created two file lists, i apologize@Jacobr365

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can easily be solved using pandas. The following piece of code will read the files A_1 - A_10 and B_1 - B_10 and then horizontally append the respective files, resulting in 10 data frames in the end.

```
import pandas

dataFrames_A = []
dataFrames_B = []

# file count of each type A or B
fileCount = 10

for i in range(1,fileCount+1):
    fileName_A = 'C:/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/A_' + str(i) + '.txt'
    fileName_B = 'C:/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/B_' + str(i) + '.txt'

    dataFrames_A.append(pandas.read_csv(fileName_A, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8'))
    dataFrames_B.append(pandas.read_csv(fileName_B, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8'))

mergedDataFrames = []
for i in range(0,fileCount):
    mergedDataFrames.append(pandas.concat([dataFrames_A[i], dataFrames_B[i]], axis=1))

for i, dataFrame in enumerate(mergedDataFrames):
    fileName = 'C:/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/A_B_' + str(i+1) + '.txt'
    dataFrame.to_csv(fileName, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Hi Anoop, thanks for your suggestion, don't I have to specify the path of the files? And where will be the merged 10 files be saved? I am trying to have the output in txt format also.

Comment: This is assuming that your script and the input txt files are in the same directory. And your output files will also be saved in the same directory. You can always provide the path information anywhere you feel the need to. And lastly, the output files is stored as .txt as you can see in the variable fileName in the last for loop and the separator is also '\t'

Comment: I tried following your instructions, got this two error, 1: This one after for i in range(1,fileCount+1)   Error:  (File b'A_1.txt' does not exist) and 2: after mergedDataFrames = [] Error: (list index out of range). The paths of my files are:C:\Users\Hrihaan\Desktop, your help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code you're executing in your question? And also your file names along with the full path?

Comment: Hi Anoop, that's the full path>>C:\Users\Hrihaan\Desktop\A_1.txt and C:\Users\Hrihaan\Desktop\B_1.txt, for the code I used it exactly as you instructed.

Comment: Are you using single backslash '\' in the file path? I have edited the code with your file paths. Can you copy the code and try to run it?

Comment: It's working now Anoop, thanks a lot and apologize for my poor Python Knowledge.

Comment: Glad to be of help!! If you've found the solution, can you approve this as the correct answer?

Comment: Hi Anoop, I accepted the answer of Lev before, I don't think they are allowing me to choose 2 answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just combine lines regardless of the content, you don't need [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
import os

def path(dirname, letter, index): # build the absolute path of a single file
    return os.path.join(dirname, '{}_{}.txt'.format(letter, index))

d = 'C:/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop'
for i in range(1, 11):
    with open(path(d, 'C', i), 'w') as fout, open(
           path(d, 'A', i)) as fa, open(path(d, 'B', i)) as fb:
         for line_a, line_b in zip(fa, fb):
             fout.write(line_a.rstrip('\n') + line_b)
```

This doesn't insert any delimiter between the two, which you will need if these are tab- or comma-separated files. You can add an appropriate delimiter in the last line of the code, for example:

```
fout.write(line_a.rstrip('\n') + ' ' + line_b)
```

Alternatively, you can use another method involving actual parsing of the files.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful reply, I tried but it is not finding the files I guess, Error: (FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'A_1').

Comment: @Hrihaan I forgot the `.txt` (was looking at your question and not your code). Fixed it now.

Comment: @Hrihaan made another edit to use full paths more easily.

Comment: Hi, That code is working like a charm, Thanks, would you please suggest how can I have SPACE as the delimiter? @Lev

Answer (score 1):

For one pair of files, first, split file A's contents into an array of lines (split by the newline `'\n'` character), and do the same with file B.

Then, for each of file B's lines, append that line to A's corresponding line. If file A has a different number of lines than file B does, simply fill the rest of the shorter array with empty strings, until they have the same number of lines (so you'll have *something* to concatenate with the corresponding line).

Finally, join the lines of file A (which is now the concatenation of both files' lines) by the `'\n'` character, and do the same with file B.